# Kubernetes - Find per CPU usage for the pod

Tags: linux, kubernetes, prometheus

How do I get per core usage for my Kubernetes pod, through a command or programmatically.

I used `kubectl top` command but it just gives me overall CPU usage.

I provide 2.5 cores to my Kubernetes pod. How do I get core usage like idle time, application usage for all the cores assigned to the pod.